# Why do some java classes seem to return a value when constructed?

Tags: java, class, return

E.g.

```
import java.util.*;

public class mainXX {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(new Date());
    }
}
```

If I run this code I'm creating a new Date object but not calling any methods, it only calls the default constructor, which looks like this:

public Date() {
      this(System.currentTimeMillis());
  }

How does the System.out.println end up printing a string date (Tue Sep 27 12:04:42 EST 2011) from this declaration as a constructor can't return a value?

I know this is a simple question but I can't figure out what is happening. Thanks, m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that constructors themselves do not return values, but **the expression formed by applying the new operator** to a constructor "call", does **produce** a value.

In other words `new` is an operator.  The expression `new C ( args )` invokes the constructor `C` on the given arguments.  The result of the `new` expression is the newly constructed object.  It is the `new` operator, not the constructor, that is producing the value.  (I'm being technical and saying "producing" instead of "returning" because I think that is in the spirit of your question.)

**ADDENDUM**

By way of further explanation: Constructors, do not actually "return" objects the way methods do.  For example:

```
public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point (double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {return x;}
    public double getY() {return y;}

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }
}
```

The methods `getX`, `getY`, and `toString` return values, so when used in an expression like this

```
p.getX()
```

a value is returned.

The constructor has no return statement.  More importantly you don't call it directly.  That is you *cannot* say

```
System.out.println(Point(1, 2));
```

That would be an error.  Instead, you use a "new-expression" which has the form `new` applied to the constructor name applied to an argument list.  This invokes the constructor and produces a new object.  For example:

```
Point p = new Point(4, 3);
```

The right hand side is a newly created point object.  All I was pointing out is that nothing is returned from the constructor itself; you have to apply the `new` operator to get the point object.

Because the `new` expression produces an object, we can apply methods directly to it.  The following are all acceptable:

```
new Point(4, 3)               // produces a point object

new Point(4, 3).getX()        // produces 4

new Point(4, 3).getY()        // produces 3

new Point(4, 3).toString()    // produces "(4,3)"
```

As other answerers have pointed out, in Java when you use an object in a context where a string is expected, the `toString()` method is automatically called.  So

```
System.out.println(new Point(4, 3))
```

would actually print `(4,3)`.

Comment: Could you explain this a little further please? Thanks, m

Comment: @mAndroid, sure, np, added to answer.  Hope it helps.  Perhaps I was reading more into the question than was there?

Comment: This answer is missing an explanation of the toString() method, which is critical to understanding what's going on here, I think.

Answer (score 5):

When calling `println` on an `Object` the Object's `toString()` method will automatically called. Thus, the new Date is constructed based on the current system time, then the `Date.toString()` method is called, returning a `String`. The String is then printed to the console.

Comment: Great thanks, it's slightly confusing that you don't have to make the call explicitly. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3):

The `toString()` method, available on all Java objects, is called whenever a string representation of an object is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Tom G is not quite correct.

`System.out` is a `PrintStream`.

`PrintStream.println` is overloaded so that the value produced (the date `Object`) is printed differently to other types.

As per the [Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29), this:

- calls `print(Object)`, which
- calls `String.valueOf(Object)` (not `toString` as suggested), which
- calls `toString()` if the object isn't null

The result of that last `toString` (`valueOf`) is a String, which is then printed by `PrintStream` as indicated by the documentation.

Comment: Actually, if object is not null, String.valueOf(object) returns the value of object.toString()

Comment: The [docs of String.valueOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) are clear that the method returns a String which is the result of invoking `toString()` on the object if it's not null. The conversion to bytes--not a byte array--is handled by the PrintStream, not the `valueOf()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The method `System.out.println();` targets the value of an object in java, let it be string or integer or any other custom defined object. So when you try to invoke this method on any object the toString() method associated with that object is automatically called, resulting in that value.
Hope this clears your doubt.